# How to get rid of a vertical line in the editor pane of IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

recently a gray vertical line appeared in about the middle of the editor pane of my IntelliJIdea Community Edition 13.1.4 probably due to some manipulations with the settings that I cannot remember. I cannot find how to get rid of it, which is annoying. Who can help?
[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 224):

**Updated answer:**

Go to `Preferences` → `Editor` → `General` → `Appearance` and uncheck `Show hard wrap and visual guides`.

[image: Settings window 2020]

**Original answer:**

Go to `Settings` → `Editor` → `General` → `Appearance` and uncheck `Show Right Margin`.

[image: Settings window 2014]

You can also configure where the right margin is in the code style settings.

Comment: To me, the bigger issue is a pasted line breaking at that point.  Even with the visible line gone, a pasted line still breaks there.  How do you get rid of _that_?

Comment: Answered my own question - `Editor -> Code Style -> <your language> -> Hard Wrap At`.  I set my to 999 (the max)

Comment: Can you just update the original answer and not add the Update at the bottom of it? I only ask because I just about missed your update and this was super helpful lol

Comment: @AnthonyRussell the edit was not done by me. Also, I think it makes sense to keep the original answer since the screenshot refers to it.

Comment: This answer not relevant for current versions

Comment: Thank you, that was super annoying to have that there.

Answer (score 32):

It is called 'Show hard wrap guide' now,
located in Editor > General > Appearance

[image: Settings > Editor > General > Appearance]

Answer (score 13):

In new versions of JetBrains IDEs, Hence, After 2017, you should search **`show hard wrap guide`**. see below screenshot:

[image]

It's inside of **Editor > General > Appearance**

Answer (score 12):

In mac Command+Shift+A .. Search for "show right margin" . Press enter to turn it off. Booom

Answer (score 7):

Go to settings and type line separator in search and hard wrap it to 180

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For PyCharm 2017 and aboce it was moved, but can still be done by:

`Editor > Color Scheme > General.` Then in the new control to the right, open `Editor > Guides > Hard wrap guide`, and **uncheck** the checkbox for "*Foreground*".

Answer (score 4):

Windows JetBrains Rider 2022:

File->Settings->Editor->General->Appearance

Uncheck "Show hard wrap and visual guides (configured in Code Style options)"

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In version IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-223.7571.182, built on November 29, 2022

You can browse to:
**File** -> **Settings** -> **Editor** -> **General** -> **Appearance**

Uncheck "Show hard wrap and visual guides (configured in Code Style options)

Or optionally if you really don't want to browse this long, just search on top left search option as "Hard wrap" or "visual guides".

[image: Updated IntelliJ visuals]

Answer (score 2):

2018-10-31

Settings -> Editor -> Code Style

you can find 'Hard wrap at [value] columns'.

230 columns is good to me.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, for IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 (Community Edition):

- File
- -> Settings
- -> Editor
- -> General
- -> Appearance
- -> Uncheck "Show indent guides"