# Flutter: How can i move this line a bit?

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, flutter-layout

[image: How can i move this line to right]

How can i move this line to the right side. i'm using intellij idea and i have used a custom font which caused the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove: All you need to do is go to the editor settings, namely: `Preferences` → `Editor` → `General` → `Appearance` and uncheck `Show hard wrap guide`.

[image]

To move: Go to: `Preferences` → Type in search `Line separator` → Change value of `hard wrap at`

Original answer: [How to get rid of a vertical line in the editor pane of IntelliJ Idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25566070/how-to-get-rid-of-a-vertical-line-in-the-editor-pane-of-intellij-idea)