# How to remove the vertical line in the android studio?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

How to remove the vertical line in android studio because my code is stop expanding according to the right margin line
[image]

Comment: See: [How to get rid of a vertical line in the editor pane of IntelliJ Idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25566070/295004) or [IntelliJ configure code style](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-style.html)

Comment: Your code will wrap at that line whether you see it or not.  That's what "dart format" is designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, for IntelliJ IDEA :

- File
- Settings
- Editor
- General
- Appearance
- Uncheck "Show indent guides"